# How do i load error pages with JQuerys load()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-status-codes, custom-error-pages

I know I can load a page with `$(#…).load(url, params, callback(status, text))` and that *status* may be 'success' or 'error'). My problem: I have nicely designed errorpages for 404 and 403 and I want them to get loaded with `.load()`.

I can see that *text* is my 'nicely designed errorpage' but how do I return from *callback* function that `.load()` should continue as if the call was a HTTP-200? *callback*s documentation does not specify a return-parameter…

Comment: What do you mean by return from callback? Ask question regarding expected behaviour instead. `load()` is an ajax method and you cannot return from any ajax callback

Comment: I can see no reason in 'you cannot return from any ajax callback'.

Comment: One reason is because ajax request is async but even for sync ones. But maybe by return you mean something else than return? So why not providing your expected behaviour in question itself? Whywould you need to return something from load complete callback? Maybe i completly misunderstand what you mean

Comment: It does not matter if it is sync or async. On both success and error it calls the callback, but on success (200) it also loads the element from URL. I want that happen on error, too. Usually, one would do that by return an appropirate statement, like true/false in event handling.

Comment: I guess you mean on error you are returning a custom 404 page and you are using in url parameter of load method document fragment url to target only specific element on success page. Is that it??? If ya, consider instead to use $.ajax method and handle error and succes differently. Edit i think i completly misunderstand your question indeed....

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what you're trying to tell. Lets keep this client-side; the *server* does return 404/403 or 200… The JQuery *client* fills a div with either actual content (full 200 HTML page) or he gets a full HTML 404/403 from the server. He still should handle that like he's handling 200: in that case fill the div with the provided error page

Comment: So i guess you just want: `if (textStatus === "error") {$(this).html(responseText); return;}`? With relavant callback signature: `function (responseText, textStatus, jqXHR)`